# FIND 4 sets of 5-letter words using these non-repeating letters:

Tags: word, knowledge, language, english, letters

Find 4 sets of 5-letter words using these non-repeating letters:

> N, C, A, V, M, S, E, Y, U, R, O, F, G, T, I, L, H, K, P, D

Comment: https://new.wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=N+C+A+V+M+S+E+Y+U+R+O+F+G+T+I+L+H+K+P+D&language=english&t=500&d=&include=&exclude=&n=5&m=5&a=n&l=n&q=n&k=1&source=adv

Comment: @msh210 maybe you can transform this to an answer.

Comment: I wrote a program that could brute-force it, but then I calculated based on some benchmarks that it would take somewhere between 13 and 15 years to finish running!

Comment: The real puzzle is, why include "K" and omit "B"?

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few:

> Vinyl Forks Caged Thump
>  Decaf Vigor Lymph Stunk
>  Given Forty Chalk Dumps
>  Lumpy Kings Caved Forth
>
> I suspect there are many more.

Edit for an explanation of my process:

> There was no real systematic way I found these. I mostly just tried to think of words that used few vowels and some of the more uncommon consonants, which seemed like it would leave many more possibilities for three other words. It wasn't very difficult to find these by basic mental brute force, which is why I believe there must be many more valid solutions.

Comment: +1, but will you please add in how you arrived at those. Did you separate the vowels into groups of 4 and then eyeball groups of consonants into those groups and search a dictionary? Or was there more to it? I ask since there are lots of ways to split 20 into 4 distinct groups of 5. (11.7+ billion if I calculated correctly)

Answer (score 1):

[The Internet Anagram Server : Anagrams for: NCAVMSEYUROFGTILHKPD](https://new.wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=NCAVMSEYUROFGTILHKPD+&language=english&t=500&d=4&include=&exclude=&n=5&m=5&a=n&l=n&q=n&k=1&source=adv) produces:

```
5784 found. Displaying first 500:
Decaf Vying Hulks Tromp
Decaf Vigor Lymph Stunk
Decaf Vigor Myths Plunk
Faced Vying Hulks Tromp
Faced Vigor Lymph Stunk
Faced Vigor Myths Plunk
Caged Flunk Moths Privy
Caged Forks Thump Vinyl
Cadge Flunk Moths Privy
Cadge Forks Thump Vinyl
Ached Folks Vying Trump
Caked Flung Moths Privy
…
```